# Tally function in Loop

Tags: tally

```
f[x] := -x + 1;
 g[x] := -x - 1;
 
 c = {g[0], f[0]}
 
 For[i = 1, i < 8, i++, a = Map[f, c]; b = Map[g, c]; c = Join[a, b]; 
  Tally[Sort[c]]]]
```

It does not show the output of the set C when I type Tally inside the loop body, but when I type Tally after executing the loop, it works fine for the last iteration, can anyone help me by figuring out how to show the output of tally when it is mentioned inside the loop

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.